# WP_Query and DES sort for Custom Taxonomy based upon a meta field?

Tags: wp-query, functions, custom-taxonomy

Is it possible to filter events (WP Query) within a Custom Taxonomy archive by ‘Start Dates’?

I create a Custom Post Type called “Events” and in that “Events” is a *Start Date*

When I view Custom Taxonomy listing data from the Custom Post Type I’d like for the events to be filtered by the *Start Date* in a DES manner.

I thought this code would work - am I on the right track?

```
//Using Wordpress Pre-Get filter to order the custom taxonomy by custom field
function customize_customtaxonomy_archive_display ( $query ) {
    if (($query->is_main_query()) && (is_tax('country')))

    $query->set( 'post_type', 'your-post-type' );  // not sure??               
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'start_date' ); // this is meta_field          
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}

 add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'customize_customtaxonomy_archive_display' );
```

The above comes from here: [Custom Taxonomy order by Custom Field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/292560/custom-taxonomy-order-by-custom-field)

I thought the above would work for me but it didn't - perhaps because I wasn't sure what to add in the **$query->set( 'post_type', 'your-post-type' );**  bit

What should I be adding there?

Comment: `'your-post-type'` will be your "Events" type slug, probably `'event'`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. You shouldn't need to set the post type. Your taxonomy archive is presumably already querying the correct post type.

```
function customize_customtaxonomy_archive_display ( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_tax( 'country' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'start_date' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
```

Note:

- `$query->is_main_query()` is redundant when checking `$query->is_tax()`, because (as far as I'm aware) secondary queries can never be a taxonomy archive.
- Setting the posts per page has nothing to do with sorting, so I've omitted it.
- You need to use `{}` with `if` statements, otherwise the condition will only apply to the next line. The original code you've copied will apply that sorting and posts per page value to *all* queries. Even if you only have one line, omitting the brackets is considered poor practice.

Comment: Thanks Jacob - ok - so how can I sort a custom taxonomy by a ‘start date’? The ‘start date’ is from a custom post type. Is there any resource or suggestion of how I can do this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. That's in my answer (and your original question). You were asking about the `post_type` property. If this isn't working, then the solution depends on how you're storing the date.

Comment: Ok got it - thanks - am reading this on the road - pardon brevity